# How do I install Ubuntu on an Android tablet?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I was trying to install Ubuntu on an ARM based Android tablet. I figured that most of the solutions are running virtually. How do I install Ubuntu natively on ARM tablet, instead run it as a virtual image?

Comment: ARM is very fragmented right now, so for example, if something works on ARM7 processors will not work for ARM11. We'd need to know what hardware you have and if [Ubuntu ARM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM) supports it.

Comment: OP do you still need help regarding this? Please post an answer if you found a solution, thanks. :)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned.  It's a good question, but I don't see any responses to the comments as far back as October of last year.